# wsdisplay color map not being retrieved correctly

Tags: c, color-palette, netbsd

I've been trying to use [`wscons`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?wscons++NetBSD-5.1) and [`wsdisplay`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?wsdisplay++NetBSD-5.1) on NetBSD 5.1.2 (using the VESA framebuffer implementation) recently and I've encountered a bit of a problem:

I can *set* color maps successfully and they look correct but ***getting* color maps seems to return incorrect data**, such that when I try to restore the original color map once the program has finished, all the colors are incorrect:

[image: Vim, showing the program's source with a strange color map]

Here's a reduced program causing the problem (note that it must be run either as `root` or as the user logged in on the second virtual terminal (`/dev/ttyE1`)):

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dev/wscons/wsconsio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argc, (void)argv;
    int tty = open("/dev/ttyE1", O_RDWR | O_EXCL);
    if(tty == -1) {
        perror("error opening tty");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    struct wsdisplay_fbinfo fbinfo;
    if(ioctl(tty, WSDISPLAYIO_GINFO, &fbinfo) == -1) {
        perror("error retrieving framebuffer info");
        close(tty);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    uint8_t *cmap_data = malloc(fbinfo.cmsize * 3);
    if(cmap_data == NULL) {
        perror("error allocating memory for color map data");
        close(tty);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    struct wsdisplay_cmap cmap;
    cmap.index = 0;
    cmap.count = fbinfo.cmsize;
    cmap.red   = &cmap_data[fbinfo.cmsize * 0];
    cmap.green = &cmap_data[fbinfo.cmsize * 1];
    cmap.blue  = &cmap_data[fbinfo.cmsize * 2];
    if(ioctl(tty, WSDISPLAYIO_GETCMAP, &cmap) == -1) {
        perror("error getting color map");
        close(tty), free(cmap_data);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(ioctl(tty, WSDISPLAYIO_PUTCMAP, &cmap) == -1) {
        perror("error putting color map");
        close(tty), free(cmap_data);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    free(cmap_data);
    close(tty);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**What am I doing wrong** and how can I make it retrieve and restore color maps correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cause

I looked into the problem more and it appears that some kernel memory is either uninitialized or getting corrupted. Specifically, `sc_cmap_red`, `sc_cmap_green`, and `sc_cmap_blue` of `struct vesafb_softc` (in [`vesafbvar.h`](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/arch/i386/bios/Attic/vesafbvar.h?rev=1.7&content-type=text/plain&only_with_tag=MAIN) on lines 89 to 91) contain incorrect data. This is somewhat surprising, as lines 719 to 722 of [`vesafb.c`](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/arch/i386/bios/Attic/vesafb.c?rev=1.31&content-type=text/plain&only_with_tag=MAIN) initialize it:

```c
/* Fill in the softc colourmap arrays */
sc->sc_cmap_red[i / 3] = rasops_cmap[i + 0];
sc->sc_cmap_green[i / 3] = rasops_cmap[i + 1];
sc->sc_cmap_blue[i / 3] = rasops_cmap[i + 2];
```

It contains incorrect data even if I move that out of the `if` statement it's in, so it might be getting corrupted rather than being uninitialized.

The driver *is* able to get and set color maps correctly, however; it just cannot seem to get the initial one in `struct vesafb_softc` right.

## Workaround

A simple solution would be to make a program re-set the default color map. As the above snippet indicated, it was *supposed* to get its initial colors from `rasops_cmap`, which happens to be defined on lines 55 to 122 in [`rasops.c`](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/dev/rasops/rasops.c?rev=1.58&content-type=text/plain&only_with_tag=MAIN):

```c
/* ANSI colormap (R,G,B). Upper 8 are high-intensity */
const u_char rasops_cmap[256*3] = {
    /* ... */
};
```

With those colors, you can make a program that sets that as the current color map. I had to make a few changes so the cursor didn't disappear, but it mostly worked.

## Better Solution

As I was looking around for more information, I had found [this blog post](http://blog.netbsd.org/tnf/entry/heads_up_x86_framebuffer_console). When I recompiled the kernel with [`genfb(4)`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?genfb++NetBSD-current) rather than [`vesafb(4)`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vesafb++NetBSD-5.0), the kernel hung at boot. It turns out this was because the bootloader I was using was not new enough to pass the required parameters to the kernel.

I happened to look at the [NetBSD 6.0 changelog](http://www.netbsd.org/changes/changes-6.0.html) and noticed this entry:

> - **[amd64](http://www.netbsd.org/changes/changes-6.0.html#port-amd64), [i386](http://www.netbsd.org/changes/changes-6.0.html#port-i386)**
>     The bootloader has been enhanced to support framebuffer consoles using VESA BIOS extensions. These changes allow the x86 ports to work with the [genfb(4)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?genfb++NetBSD-current) driver, and obsoletes the i386-only [vesafb(4)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vesafb++NetBSD-5.0) driver. *[jmcneill 20090216]*

I downloaded NetBSD 6.0_BETA and booted it from the boot prompt like this:

```
> vesa 640x480x8
> boot netbsd
```

...and everything worked.

#### In short, using a newer version of NetBSD and ditching [`vesafb(4)`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vesafb++NetBSD-5.0) solves the problem.